# Distinct max values or only one maximum value from the serial number

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have a database (with two columns "id" and "serial") with serial numbers. For example:

```
id |Serial
10 | A18D003.000106
12 | A13D002.000100
122| A19D004.000107
```

There are many more numbers, but let's assume there are about 50 of each type of key:

```
From A18D003.00001 to 00052
From A13D002.00001 to 00053
From A19D004.00001 to 00057
```

I want to get the maximum value of the last 5 digits of the serial number. So the following should appear:

```
A18D003.00052
A13D002.00053
A19D004.00057
```

and get the absolute maximum value of what is after the dot:

```
A18D003.00052 -> 00052
A13D002.00053 -> 00053
A19D004.00057 -> 00057
```

It should only display:

```
A19D004.00057
```

How to do this in Firebird?

Comment: It is unclear to me how those three forms of ids/keys/whatever in your question relate to one another. What do the first set of IDs (`A18D003.000106` etc), have to do with the rest of your question? What is the id, what is the serial? What is the logic of converting `A18D003.00001: 00052` to `A18D003.00052`?

Comment: It's not about conversions - the point is that the serial number starts with: A18D003.00001 and ends with A18D003.00052 - The maximum value does not correspond to the ID in any way - the maximum value is in a random line and I want to know it - the keys differ with the prefix
I want to get only the maximum value of what is after the prefix, that is:
A18D003.00052 -> 00052

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substring`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-functions-string.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-substring) to extract the last part of the serial, [order by](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-orderby) it descending, and then only [fetch](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch) the first row:

```sql
select val
from serial
order by substring(val from 9) desc
fetch first row only
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=213309564fcb403103763e02bcd03311

This example assumes that the serial always has the separating dot in position 8, otherwise you may need to use the regular expression form of `substring` (e.g. `substring(val similar '%.#"%#"' escape '#')`), or use [`position`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-functions-string.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-position).

Given the complication mentioned in the comments of having serials with 5 or 6 digits, you can also try using one of the following approaches:

1. [Trim](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-functions-string.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-trim) leading zeroes and cast to integer:

   ```sql
   cast(trim(leading '0' from substring(val from 9)) as integer)
   ```
2. As a variant of the previous, use substring to extract the number:

   ```sql
   cast(substring(val similar '%.0*#"([1-9][0-9]*)|0#"' escape '#') as integer)
   ```
3. Left pad ([`lpad`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-functions-string.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-lpad)) zeroes to a common length (for simplicity, I'm assuming 6 here):

   ```sql
   lpad(substring(val from 9), 6, '0')
   ```

Comment: In this form is working , but i have more serial keys and this code not return max value of serial.

Comment: @statisticspp Please provide an example where this doesn't work.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=c2d4a7defa48a29785717c5998e37637

Comment: @statisticspp You have suffixes of 5 and 6 characters. How do you want to handle those? Do you really just want to sort on the last 5 characters like you mention in the question, or is there a chance that serials like `A13D002.100157` exist and need to be handled properly? Also, are these suffixes always fully numeric or can they also contain other characters?

Comment: What to do in this situation - can I avoid the first zero somehow?Sufixes will always be numeric, but until a one appears in the first character of 6, we assume that the number is 5 characters long.

Comment: There are several approaches possible, left pad with zeroes to a common length, trim leading zeroes and convert to integer before sorting, use a collation that applies numeric sort (not sure if that works in this case tbh), etc.

Comment: There is no easier way of some nested command that could be used?

The point is, the database is dead - it already has about 15,000 serial numbers from different groups and I want to use what I already have.

Comment: @statisticspp What do you mean with "nested command"? You can create a [function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-ddl-function.html) to encapsulate things, if that's what you mean. Or you could add a calculated column to the table, or define a view and use that, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have task like that it seems that "Serial" is actualyl two fields, not one. And the table is NOT notmalized yet. So, you most probable have to normilize it.

*See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization*

You would have first to add new `VARCHAR` columns (or maybe `VARCHAR` and `INTEGER`), `SERIAL_PART_1` and `SERIAL_PART_2`

*See [Ch. 5.1.2.](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-db-alter) `ALTER DATABASE`*

From that point you have two strategies.

---

If you can refactor all of your applications, the natural approach would be to remove the old "complex" column and to recreate it as an expression, based on the two "atom" columns. That way your applications would no be able to write into that "complex" column and whould be discouraged  from using it in `WHERE` or `GROUP` or `ORDER` clauses (use new "atom" aolumns instead). Database-wise this seems a normal strategy, but can you effect all your applications in sync - i don't know.

If you can - you have to do a one-time data migration, and then re-work your applications. From now on they should only read the older, "compound" serial columns, never write into them and almost never filter by them.

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version
>      , rdb$character_set_name
> from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> VERSION | RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME                                                                                                      
> :------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 3.0.5   | UTF8
> ```

> ```
> create table serial (
>   val varchar(50) not null
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A18D003.00052');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A13D002.00053');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19D004.00057');
> ```

> ```
> select val
> from serial
> order by substring(val from 9) desc
> fetch first row only
> ```
>
> ```
> | VAL           |
> | :------------ |
> | A19D004.00057 |
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19F104.00057');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A18D003.00010');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A13D002.0008');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19D004.00000025');
> ```

> ```
> --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71555536   alternative answer
>
> alter table serial
>   add serial_part_1 varchar(8) not null
>  ,add serial_part_2 integer not null
>  ,add serial_part_2_text COMPUTED BY (lpad(serial_part_2, 6, '0'))
> ```

> ```
> -- make sure lpad (6, xxx ) always work properly
> alter table serial
>   add check ((serial_part_2 >= 0) and (serial_part_2 < 1000000))
> ```

> ```
> -- STRATEGY database-first, one-time data migration, needs refactoring of all applications
>
> -- should this be just a non-unique index (allowing rows repetitions)
> -- or should that be a PRIMARY KEY instead ???
>
> create index idx_serial_by_parts on serial(serial_part_1,serial_part_2)
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_serial_by_part2 on serial(serial_part_2)
> ```

> ```
> -- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-string
>
> update serial set
>   serial_part_1 = LEFT(val, POSITION( '.' IN val) - 1)
>  ,serial_part_2 = SUBSTRING(val FROM POSITION( '.' IN val) + 1)
> ```

7 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from serial
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL              | SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT
> :--------------- | :------------ | ------------: | :-----------------
> A18D003.00052    | A18D003       |            52 | 000052            
> A13D002.00053    | A13D002       |            53 | 000053            
> A19D004.00057    | A19D004       |            57 | 000057            
> A19F104.00057    | A19F104       |            57 | 000057            
> A18D003.00010    | A18D003       |            10 | 000010            
> A13D002.0008     | A13D002       |             8 | 000008            
> A19D004.00000025 | A19D004       |            25 | 000025
> ```

> ```
> alter table serial 
>   drop val
> ```

> ```
> alter table serial
>   add val COMPUTED BY ( serial_part_1 || '.' || serial_part_2_text  )
> ```

> ```
> select * from serial
> ```
>
> ```
> SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT | VAL           
> :------------ | ------------: | :----------------- | :-------------
> A18D003       |            52 | 000052             | A18D003.000052
> A13D002       |            53 | 000053             | A13D002.000053
> A19D004       |            57 | 000057             | A19D004.000057
> A19F104       |            57 | 000057             | A19F104.000057
> A18D003       |            10 | 000010             | A18D003.000010
> A13D002       |             8 | 000008             | A13D002.000008
> A19D004       |            25 | 000025             | A19D004.000025
> ```

> ```
> select SERIAL_PART_1, Max(SERIAL_PART_2), Max(val)
> from serial
> group by SERIAL_PART_1
> ```
>
> ```
> SERIAL_PART_1 | MAX | MAX           
> :------------ | --: | :-------------
> A13D002       |  53 | A13D002.000053
> A18D003       |  52 | A18D003.000052
> A19D004       |  57 | A19D004.000057
> A19F104       |  57 | A19F104.000057
> ```

> ```
> with mx as ( select Max(SERIAL_PART_2) as mx2 from serial )
> select * from serial, mx 
>   where SERIAL_PART_2 = mx.mx2
> ```
>
> ```
> SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT | VAL            | MX2
> :------------ | ------------: | :----------------- | :------------- | --:
> A19D004       |            57 | 000057             | A19D004.000057 |  57
> A19F104       |            57 | 000057             | A19F104.000057 |  57
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=1226405ede67ba41f3e167ad35fba64b)*

---

Alternative strategy would be to keep BOTH new and old columns, and use a smart trigger to keep synchronizing those data values in both directions.

That would let you keep old applications, yet would require a very careful online data conversion-synchronization programming.

For example, in the sample below i did not think much about different combinations of NULL and not-NULL data values. To use this approach in production it would be your task to check for all possible data value sets, correct and broken, and to arm your code against any bad combination.

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version
>      , rdb$character_set_name
> from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> VERSION | RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME                                                                                                      
> :------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 3.0.5   | UTF8
> ```

> ```
> create table serial (
>   val varchar(50) not null
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A18D003.00052');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A13D002.00053');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19D004.00057');
> ```

> ```
> select val
> from serial
> order by substring(val from 9) desc
> fetch first row only
> ```
>
> ```
> | VAL           |
> | :------------ |
> | A19D004.00057 |
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19F104.00057');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A18D003.00010');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A13D002.0008');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19D004.00000025');
> ```

> ```
> --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71555536   alternative answer
>
> alter table serial
>   add serial_part_1 varchar(8) not null
>  ,add serial_part_2 integer not null
>  ,add serial_part_2_text COMPUTED BY (lpad(serial_part_2, 6, '0'))
> ```

> ```
> -- make sure lpad (6, xxx ) always work properly
> alter table serial
>   add check ((serial_part_2 >= 0) and (serial_part_2 < 1000000))
> ```

> ```
> -- STRATEGY applications-first, on-change two-ways data migration, 
> -- hopefully can avoid immediate refactoring of all applications
>
> -- should this be just a non-unique index (allowing rows repetitions)
> -- or should that be a PRIMARY KEY instead ???
>
> create index idx_serial_by_parts on serial(serial_part_1,serial_part_2)
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_serial_by_part2 on serial(serial_part_2)
> ```

> ```
> -- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-trgr-crtalter
> -- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-triggercreate
>
> CREATE TRIGGER serial_data_synchronize
>   ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
>   ON serial
> AS
> BEGIN
>   -- the next condition might need defensive programming
>   -- what should be  TRUE OR FALSE OR NULL ?
>   IF ( (NEW.val IS NULL) 
>        OR (NEW.serial_part_1 <> OLD.serial_part_1)
>        OR (NEW.serial_part_2 <> OLD.serial_part_2)
>   ) THEN BEGIN
>     NEW.val = NEW.serial_part_1 || '.' || NEW.serial_part_2_text;
>     EXIT;
>   END
>
>   IF ( (NEW.val IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.val)
>        OR ( NEW.serial_part_1 IS NULL ) 
>        OR ( NEW.serial_part_2 IS NULL ) 
>   ) THEN BEGIN
>     NEW.serial_part_1 = LEFT(NEW.val, POSITION( '.' IN NEW.val) - 1);  
>     NEW.serial_part_2 = SUBSTRING(NEW.val FROM POSITION( '.' IN NEW.val) + 1);
>   END
> END
> ```

> ```
> select * from serial
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL              | SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT
> :--------------- | :------------ | ------------: | :-----------------
> A18D003.00052    |               |             0 | null              
> A13D002.00053    |               |             0 | null              
> A19D004.00057    |               |             0 | null              
> A19F104.00057    |               |             0 | null              
> A18D003.00010    |               |             0 | null              
> A13D002.0008     |               |             0 | null              
> A19D004.00000025 |               |             0 | null
> ```

> ```
> update serial set val = val; -- trigger the trigger
> ```

7 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from serial
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL              | SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT
> :--------------- | :------------ | ------------: | :-----------------
> A18D003.00052    | A18D003       |            52 | 000052            
> A13D002.00053    | A13D002       |            53 | 000053            
> A19D004.00057    | A19D004       |            57 | 000057            
> A19F104.00057    | A19F104       |            57 | 000057            
> A18D003.00010    | A18D003       |            10 | 000010            
> A13D002.0008     | A13D002       |             8 | 000008            
> A19D004.00000025 | A19D004       |            25 | 000025
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (val) values ('A19F104.00042');
> ```

> ```
> insert into serial (serial_part_1,serial_part_2) values ('A19F104', 21);
> ```

> ```
> select * from serial
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL              | SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT
> :--------------- | :------------ | ------------: | :-----------------
> A18D003.00052    | A18D003       |            52 | 000052            
> A13D002.00053    | A13D002       |            53 | 000053            
> A19D004.00057    | A19D004       |            57 | 000057            
> A19F104.00057    | A19F104       |            57 | 000057            
> A18D003.00010    | A18D003       |            10 | 000010            
> A13D002.0008     | A13D002       |             8 | 000008            
> A19D004.00000025 | A19D004       |            25 | 000025            
> A19F104.00042    | A19F104       |            42 | 000042            
> A19F104.000021   | A19F104       |            21 | 000021
> ```

> ```
> update serial 
>    set serial_part_2 = 12
>  where val = 'A19F104.00042'
> ```

> ```
> update serial 
>    set val = 'A18D003.00022'
>  where serial_part_2 = 10
> ```

> ```
> select * from serial
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL              | SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT
> :--------------- | :------------ | ------------: | :-----------------
> A18D003.00052    | A18D003       |            52 | 000052            
> A13D002.00053    | A13D002       |            53 | 000053            
> A19D004.00057    | A19D004       |            57 | 000057            
> A19F104.00057    | A19F104       |            57 | 000057            
> A18D003.00022    | A18D003       |            22 | 000022            
> A13D002.0008     | A13D002       |             8 | 000008            
> A19D004.00000025 | A19D004       |            25 | 000025            
> A19F104.000012   | A19F104       |            12 | 000012            
> A19F104.000021   | A19F104       |            21 | 000021
> ```

> ```
> select SERIAL_PART_1, Max(SERIAL_PART_2), Max(val), LIST(val, ', ')
> from serial
> group by SERIAL_PART_1
> ```
>
> ```
> SERIAL_PART_1 | MAX | MAX           | LIST                                         
> :------------ | --: | :------------ | :--------------------------------------------
> A13D002       |  53 | A13D002.0008  | A13D002.0008, A13D002.00053                  
> A18D003       |  52 | A18D003.00052 | A18D003.00022, A18D003.00052                 
> A19D004       |  57 | A19D004.00057 | A19D004.00000025, A19D004.00057              
> A19F104       |  57 | A19F104.00057 | A19F104.000012, A19F104.000021, A19F104.00057
> ```

> ```
> with mx as ( select Max(SERIAL_PART_2) as mx2 from serial )
> select serial.* from serial, mx 
>   where SERIAL_PART_2 = mx.mx2
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL           | SERIAL_PART_1 | SERIAL_PART_2 | SERIAL_PART_2_TEXT
> :------------ | :------------ | ------------: | :-----------------
> A19D004.00057 | A19D004       |            57 | 000057            
> A19F104.00057 | A19F104       |            57 | 000057
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=9f73c221457e2f9c95fd5023aa01e9bd)*

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your (Mark Rotteveel) statement a bit and I must say it works - I used RIGHT instead of substring

```
select val
from serial
order by RIGHT (serial, 5) desc
fetch first row only
```